# Typescript Convert Date to Json Format "/Date(1238540400000)/"

Tags: typescript, date

Hello I am using Angular7 and Typescript Service in which I am adding some Data to database, Now the problem is I have to put a Date paramater as a json Date format to complete the action, for example The date "21-01-2015" needs to be converted like "/Date(1238540400000)/".
Any Help Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello issue resolved by doing this:

```
var startdate = <unknown>(JSON.stringify((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('periodstartdate')).value));
    var startdates=<Date>startdate;

    var d=startdates[10];
    var dd=startdates[9];
    var m=startdates[7];
    var mm=startdates[6];
    var y=startdates[4];
    var yy=startdates[3];
    var yyy=startdates[2];
    var yyyy=startdates[1];

    var time=new Date(yyyy+yyy+yy+y,mm+m,dd+d,0, 0,0,0);

    var cpastartdate="/Date(" + time.getTime() + ")/";
```